If a function is in all Sobolev spaces $H^j(S^{n-1})$ then its reciprocal is also
If $f \in \bigcap_j H^j(S^{n-1})$ and its continuous with nowhere $0$, does this imply that $\frac{1}{f} \in \bigcap_j H^j(S^{n-1})?$
I was thinking we could find a sequence $f_n$ that converges in $H^j$ for all $j$ (and therefore uniformly) to $f$, w.l.o.g $f_n$ is nowhere 0 and then try to show that $\| f_n^{-1} \|$ is bounded in $H^j$, so using a compact embedding (if it exists for spheres) to find a subsequence which should converge towards $f^{-1}$, hence $f^{-1}$ is in $H^j$
However I don't know how to do this, any help would be appreciated thank you.

The most direct proof is to use Sobolev Embedding Theorem for Manifolds without boundary (see Aubin: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-13006-3). The Theorem roughly says that for compact manifolds without boundary, this is true of $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ then we have that $H^{\frac{n-1}{2} + k}(\mathbb{S}^{n-1}) \subset C^k(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})$. Since $f\in \bigcap_{j}H^j(\mathbb{S}^{n-1}) = C^\infty(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})$ and $f$ is non vanishing, then $\frac{1}{f} \in C^\infty(\mathbb{S}^{n-1}) = \bigcap_{j}H^j(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})$.

Thanks for the answer, but could you specify which theorem in the book? I sadly couldn't find it. And also is there any other way of proving this (e.g using spherical harmonics as basis?), thanks

Theorem 2.20 in Aubin's text, the one in Hebey isn't the one I had in mind when I originally wrote the answer. I've since updated it with Aubin's book.
